# Changing direction of critical footnotes in Reledmac with Arabic

Tags: footnotes, arabic, reledmac

Trying to publish a document in Arabic with critical footnotes in Arabic. I could not get the footnotes lined up the right way: RTL. I run over the answered question, but did not find one that matches exactly my issue. I appreciate any help. Here is a MWE

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\Xbeforeinserting[A]{\LTR}
    \Xlemmaseparator[A]{[} 
    \Xafterlemmaseparator[A]{0.5em}
    \Xbeforelemmaseparator[A]{0.25em}
    \Xwrapcontent[A]{\textarabic}
    \Xwraplemma[A]{\RL}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[locale = tunisia]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Amiri}
\usepackage{bidi}

\firstlinenum{1} \linenumincrement{1} \lineation{page}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Afootnoterule}{\right@footnoterule}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{Arabic}
\beginnumbering
\pstart[\setRL]

انطلقت الثورة الليبية منذ أكثر من سنة متوازية مع ثورات الربيع العربي الأخرى التي أطاحت ببعض حكام البلدان العربية، وما إن وافقت الجامعة العربية وأمريكا وأوروبا على ضرورة تدخل \edtext{\textarabic{منظمة حلف شمال الأطلسي}}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{الأمم المتحدة}}}في المسألة حتى دخلت تركيا على الخط وقامت بإيصال مواد إغاثية وعسكرية دعما للثوار الليبيين. وهذا التدخل التركي يعكس الواقع الجديد  في ملف العلاقات الخارجية بين تركيا والشرق الأوسط، ألا وهو تعاظم دور تركيا في العالم الناطق بلغة الضاد، حيث باتت تركيا تنتهج سياسة خارجية نشطة في القضايا الشائكة والعالقة في \edtext{\textarabic{الشرق الأوسط}}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{الشرق عموما}}}ومع هذا الاتجاه الجديد في سياسات تركيا، ينبغي تحديد معالم دور تركيا الجديد، ومحددات هذا الدور في ضوء التغيرات الأخيرة في المنطقة، وكذلك  تحديد آراء العرب حيال الموقف التركي في الشرق الأوسط.

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I was in holiday. You need at least the version 3.31.3 of reledmac, which fixed a bug.

To get the correct order of the notes in paragraphed footnote, you need to switch to `RTL` before the groups of notes are printed, using `Xbhookgroup`. You must use `\Xbeforeinserting{\LTR}`, because, howerwise, reledmac will be disturberd to build paragraphe node, as it is conceived for LTR mode.

An other problem is that the dash switch to a LTR context, and so not put in the right way. You need to redefine the separator to inserate null space, in ordre to be kept in RTL it `\Xlinerangeseparator{\null-\null}`.

Here, something which should be ok for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[locale = tunisia]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Amiri}
\usepackage{bidi}

\firstlinenum{1} \linenumincrement{1} \lineation{page}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Afootnoterule}{\right@footnoterule\par}
\makeatother


\Xarrangement{paragraph}

\Xbhookgroup[A]{\RTL}
\Xafterlemmaseparator[A]{0.5em}
\Xbeforelemmaseparator[A]{0.25em}
\Xlinerangeseparator{\null-\null}
\Xbeforeinserting{\LTR}
\begin{document}
\begin{Arabic}
\beginnumbering
\pstart[\setRL]

انطلقت الثورة الليبية منذ أكثر من سنة متوازية مع ثورات الربيع العربي الأخرى التي أطاحت ببعض حكام البلدان العربية، وما إن وافقت الجامعة العربية وأمريكا وأوروبا على ضرورة تدخل \edtext{\textarabic{منظمة حلف شمال الأطلسي}}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{الأمم المتحدة}}}في المسألة حتى دخلت تركيا على الخط وقامت بإيصال مواد إغاثية وعسكرية دعما للثوار الليبيين. وهذا التدخل التركي يعكس الواقع الجديد  في ملف العلاقات الخارجية بين تركيا والشرق الأوسط، ألا وهو تعاظم دور تركيا في العالم الناطق بلغة الضاد، حيث باتت تركيا تنتهج سياسة خارجية نشطة في القضايا الشائكة والعالقة في \edtext{\textarabic{الشرق الأوسط}}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{الشرق عموما}}}ومع هذا الاتجاه الجديد في سياسات تركيا، ينبغي تحديد معالم دور تركيا الجديد، ومحددات هذا الدور في ضوء التغيرات الأخيرة في المنطقة، وكذلك  تحديد آراء العرب حيال الموقف التركي في الشرق الأوسط.

\pend
\endnumbering

\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had put the command \Xbhookgroup[A]{\RTL} earlier but noted that it did not change anything. As for the line: \pretocmd{\printlines}{\textenglish\bgroup}{}{} it did change the critical footnote numbers in the right place. By changing \textenglish to \textarabic I get the order of referred lines right, in RTL ...3-2 instead of ...2-3 But the footnote paragraph is still unchanged. I get the critical footnotes ordered in LTR as such: 
...3-2    ...6 They should be in \RTL:
...6       ...3-2

Comment: I sorry, I don't understand your point.

Comment: I realized that I was not clear. That's why I posted two examples: one using reledmac, with issues I stabled upon, and the same example with ednote with the issues resolved. I wan to reproduce the same example of ednote with reledmac this time around, if possible.

Comment: I have put a modffication to have 3-2. Please, delete your answer and modify your original question instead

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2019-08-28**

Would you consider using `lualatex`? In that case, you could try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arabluatex}
\usepackage[series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\Xbhookgroup[A]{\pardir TRT\textdir TRT}
\Xlemmaseparator[A]{[} 
\Xafterlemmaseparator[A]{0.5em}
\Xbeforelemmaseparator[A]{0.25em}
\Xwrapcontent[A]{\txarb}
% I think the following is needed to print subsequent line numbers in
% LTR:
\Xbhooknote[A]{\textdir TRT}
\firstlinenum{1} \linenumincrement{1} \lineation{page}

\renewcommand{\Afootnoterule}{%
  \hfill\noindent\rule[1mm]{.4\textwidth}{.15mm}}


\begin{document}
  \beginnumbering
  \pstart[\setRL\arabicfont] %
  انطلقت الثورة الليبية منذ أكثر من سنة
  متوازية مع ثورات الربيع العربي الأخرى التي أطاحت ببعض حكام البلدان
  العربية، وما إن وافقت الجامعة العربية وأمريكا وأوروبا على ضرورة تدخل
  \edtext{\txarb{منظمة حلف شمال الأطلسي}}{\Afootnote{الأمم المتحدة}}
  في المسألة حتى دخلت تركيا على الخط وقامت بإيصال مواد إغاثية وعسكرية
  دعما للثوار الليبيين. وهذا التدخل التركي يعكس الواقع الجديد في ملف
  العلاقات الخارجية بين تركيا والشرق الأوسط، ألا وهو تعاظم دور تركيا
  في العالم الناطق بلغة الضاد، حيث باتت تركيا تنتهج سياسة خارجية نشطة
  في القضايا الشائكة والعالقة في \edtext{\txarb{الشرق
      الأوسط}}{\Afootnote{الشرق عموما}} ومع هذا الاتجاه الجديد في
  سياسات تركيا، ينبغي تحديد معالم دور تركيا الجديد، ومحددات هذا الدور
  في ضوء التغيرات الأخيرة في المنطقة، وكذلك تحديد آراء العرب حيال
  الموقف التركي في الشرق الأوسط.
  \pend
  \endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT 2019-08-26**

For ease of comparison, here follows the text as it should print:

[image]

Comment: Maïeul and Robert: Thank you both for your answers! Robert got exactly what I was trying to achieve. I guess if I want to stick with Reledmac, I will need to shift from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX. I am considering the move!

Comment: I just noted an issue when using ArabLuaTeX with Reledmac: some of the ligatures have spaces and others are collapsed. This issue appears specifically in line 5 that Robert posted above. Using other fonts worsens the problem. I have used the same example, stripping it from reledmac additions and the results are fine, without any issues. Should I open a new discussion on the issue or continue on this thread?

Comment: @yacine Well spotted, I didn't notice this issue which also appears on line 2 by the way, namely where `reledmac` commands are found.  Something may be wrong in this preamble: `reledmac` has many options that I don't know.

Comment: Actually the issue occurs in each and every line, whether it contains reledmac commands or not. I just pointed at the most obvious. Not sure what the problem is. I will try to find out the issue but I must confess that my knowledge is limited. I am grateful for any help. As it stands, my projects using reledmac hit a dead end.

Comment: @yacine Not quite.  I am sure that Maïeul will find a way to solve this issue which is not related to `arabluatex`. I think that you should report this here: https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues Meanwhile, for ease of comparison, I add to my answer a snapshot of the text as it should print. (It is produced by `ekdosis`, a package yet to be published.)

Comment: @yacine I just edited again my answer. Could you check the mwe corresponding to `EDIT 2019-08-28`?  For some reason, `reledmac` does not accept Arabic environments, but inserting `\setRL\arabicfont` as argument of `\pstart` seems to work.

Comment: Yes! Your solution fixed the initial issue of paragraph direction, and glyphs and connections too. I have tried other fonts and they worked fine. There remains only one problem: When the lemma references two lines or more, the line numbers are printed in LRT not RTL: Example lines "....2-3" in Arabic it should be "....3-2 " I tried the solution proposed by Maïeul (please, see my post of Aug 15, above), but didn't work either.

Comment: @yacine I see that Maïeul edited his answer.  Maybe you should try to follow his advice (and so return to `xelatex` and `polyglossia`...)

Comment: @Maïeul and Robert Alessi Thank you both for your inputs on this issue. I have accepted Maïeul's answer because it solved the issue 100%. I think it is important to pursue further the answer of Robert Alessi because it tempts to solve the issue on LuaLaTeX. If I find any answer, I will post it here.

Comment: Good news for you, @yacine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my earlier post was not clear. I tried to reproduce the results I am trying to get using reledmac, through ednote, just to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish. 
In addition to the ordering of critical footnotes issue I noted above, I have noticed that reledmac introduces too much space between critical footnotes in a paragraph setting.

Here is the code with reledmac:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[series={A}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[locale = tunisia]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,WordSpace=2.2]{Amiri}
\usepackage{bidi}
\firstlinenum{1} \linenumincrement{1} \lineation{page}
\linenummargin{right}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Afootnoterule}{\right@footnoterule\par}
\makeatother

\Xarrangement{paragraph}

\Xparafootsep{$\parallel$}
\Xafternote[A]{0em}
\pretocmd{\printlines}{\textarabic\bgroup}{}{}
\apptocmd{\printlines}{\egroup}{}{}
\Xafterlemmaseparator[A]{0.5em}
\Xbeforelemmaseparator[A]{0.25em}
\Xwrapcontent[A]{\textarabic}
\Xbhookgroup[A]{\RTL}
\Xwraplemma[A]{\RL}
\Xafternote[A]{0em}

\begin{document}
\begin{Arabic}
\beginnumbering
\pstart[\setRL]
انطلقت \edtext{\textarabic{الثورة}}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{الاولى}}} الليبية منذ أكثر من سنة متوازية مع \edtext{\textarabic{ثورات}}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{الثانية}}} الربيع العربي الأخرى التي أطاحت ببعض حكام البلدان العربية، وما إن وافقت الجامعة العربية وأمريكا وأوروبا على ضرورة تدخل \edtext{\textarabic{منظمة حلف شمال الأطلسي}} {\Afootnote{\textarabic{الأمم المتحدة}}} في المسألة حتى دخلت تركيا على الخط وقامت بإيصال مواد إغاثية وعسكرية دعما للثوار الليبيين. وهذا التدخل التركي يعكس الواقع الجديد في ملف العلاقات الخارجية بين تركيا والشرق الأوسط، ألا وهو تعاظم دور تركيا في \edtext{\textarabic{الناطق بلغة الضاد، حيث باتت}}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{العربي}}} تركيا تنتهج سياسة خارجية نشطة في القضايا الشائكة والعالقة في \edtext{\textarabic{الشرق الأوسط}}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{الشرق عموما}}}ومع هذا الاتجاه الجديد في سياسات تركيا، ينبغي تحديد معالم دور تركيا الجديد، ومحددات هذا الدور في ضوء التغيرات الأخيرة في المنطقة، وكذلك تحديد آراء العرب حيال الموقف التركي في الشرق الأوسط.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

Here is how the result looks like:
[image: Critical footnotes with reledmac]

Roughly the same paragraph is rendered below with ednote. That's the result I want to accomplish with reledmac. Please, note the critical footnotes are in the Arabic format, RTL and no extra space between them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Junicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[locale=tunisia]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,WordSpace=2]{Amiri}
\usepackage[Bpara,modulo,right,perpage,para*]{ednotes}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\right@footnoterule\par}
\makeatother
\modulolinenumbers[1]
\renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\arabicfont\footnotesize}
\PrecedeLevelWith{A}{\setRL}
\renewcommand*{\linesfmt}[1]{\raisebox{1ex}{\linenumberfont #1}~}
\renewcommand{\lemmafmt}[1]{#1~[ }

\begin{document}
\begin{Arabic}
\resetlinenumber\pagewiselinenumbers

انطلقت \Anote{\textarabic{الثورة}}{\textarabic{الاولى}} الليبية منذ أكثر من سنة متوازية مع \Anote{\textarabic{ ثورات}}{\textarabic{الثانية}} الربيع العربي الأخرى التي أطاحت ببعض حكام البلدان العربية، وما إن وافقت الجامعة العربية وأمريكا وأوروبا على ضرورة تدخل \Anote{\textarabic{منظمة حلف شمال الأطلسي}}{\textarabic{الأمم المتحدة}}في المسألة حتى دخلت تركيا على الخط وقامت بإيصال مواد إغاثية وعسكرية دعما للثوار الليبيين. وهذا التدخل التركي يعكس الواقع الجديد في ملف العلاقات الخارجية بين تركيا والشرق الأوسط، ألا وهو تعاظم دور تركيا في العالم \Anote{\textarabic{الناطق بلغة الضاد، حيث باتت }}{\textarabic{العربي}}تركيا تنتهج سياسة خارجية نشطة في القضايا الشائكة والعالقة في \Anote{\textarabic{الشرق الأوسط}}{\textarabic{الشرق عموما}} ومع هذا الاتجاه الجديد في سياسات تركيا، ينبغي تحديد معالم دور تركيا الجديد، ومحددات هذا الدور في ضوء التغيرات الأخيرة في المنطقة، وكذلك تحديد آراء العرب حيال الموقف التركي في الشرق الأوسط.

\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

Here how the results with ednote:
[image]